# xml request & response format when using DFHLS2WS

Tags: web-services, cics

I'm using DFHLS2WS for exposing a CICS program as a SOAP service provider and able to generate wsbind and wsdl file.
My question is, where can I see the xml request & response format physically within mainframe system ?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the WSDL file that was generated by DFHLS2WS.  It will be placed on the Unix file system in the location you specified in the input to DFHLS2WS

```
WSDL=/u/userid/wsdl/FundWrap.wsdl
```

If you need to see sample SOAP input message or SOAP response, you'll need to use other tools which can create those from the WSDL file.